# How do I test App on my device in release/distribution mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I've tested my game a lot, send to apple, they approved I downloaded it from app store to realized the binary is totally different than I tested in my device...I realized it is because of the build mode, it sounds silly but...I can't figure how to run it in release mode and how to make release mode build exactly the same than debug.

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the upper left of Xcode window, there is you app name, tap it will show a menu, select "`Edit Scheme`".

If you want to run in release mode, in the `Run` tab, just change the `build configuration` to `release`, then build and run, you will be running on a build built with release mode.

[image]

Comment: I get an error then: `A valid provisioning profile was not found for this executable`. Why?

Comment: @CarmeloS, Thanks. I was looking this for some hour of the couple. You saved my time because I am facing an issue in release mode only but the same code working fine in debug mode. So now I am able to check this in release mode via breakpoints. Thanks again!!

Comment: Taking much time to build. It been around 30 minutes still app not launched. Any other changes required in Xcode 13.2.1